# Accessing an instance of IServiceProvider in an ValidationAttribute

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Hi I am trying to create a custom DataAnnotation attribute in asp.net core. Here is what I have so far:

```
   [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class StoreDupplicateAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public StoreDupplicateAttribute(IStoreManager storeManager)
    {

    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value) {

    }
}
```

I will need in my code an instance of IStoreManager.The problem is that if I do it this way I would need to pass IStoreManager as a parameter when I use the attribute.

Is there any way to access an instance of IServiceProvider to get from it my IStoreManager dependency without using constructor injection?

Comment: I'm not certain but I think you can annotate a property with `[FromServices]` to have it injected directly rather than via the constructor. I suspect, however, that this only works with controllers (hence why I'm not posting it as an answer, I don't have time to test it myself). Worth giving it a try...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also could not find an answer on a similar question, but then I figured it out. You should override other virtual IsValid method, something like this:

```
public class StoreDupplicateAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public StoreDupplicateAttribute()
    {
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        IStoreManager storeManager = validationContext.GetService(typeof(IStoreManager)) as IStoreManager;

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```